# sort an array of ranges

Tags: ruby, sorting, range

How to sort an array of ranges

```
ranges = [Range.new(0, 3, true), Range.new(3, 5, true), Range.new(5, 7, true), Range.new(7, 9, true), Range.new(9, 11, true), Range.new(11, 100, true)]
ranges.sort
=> ArgumentError: comparison of Range with Range failed
from (irb):7:in `sort'
from (irb):7
from /Users/praveena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

But when I try

```
2.0.0p247 :022 > (3...4) <=> (4...8)
=> nil
2.0.0p247 :023 > (3...4) <=> (1...2)
=> nil
```

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that range have an implementation for `<=>`, but is not complete. Lets check:

```
> Range.new(3,4) <=> Range.new(3,4)
=> 0
# It seems that it correctly identify when the two are equals

> Range.new(3,4) <=> Range.new(4,4)
=> nil
# But it seems that it fails to fail when both are different!
```

This method is defined in `Range` because it is actually defined [on the `Object` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)(!!!), thus every object has this method defined, which doesn't means it works. Actually the implementation for range is the default one. Lets check this:

```
# lets define a dummy class
class A
end
=> nil

# and create an object
a = A.new
=> #<A:0x9b1d998>

# can correctly identify when equal
a <=> a
=> 0

# but invalid answer when not equal!
a <=> 1
=> nil
```

At this point, you should now understand what is happening in your code.

It is totally understandable that range does not have a canonical `<=>` method because there is no mathematical definition for a greater range (that I know), neither a common sense definition.

Comment: I suspect that equality is well-defined math concept for a `Range`, but that there is not such a well-defined concept of "greater than" or  "less than" - at least not any good enough to make it into the language core, you can always invent something that would work for you.

Comment: @NeilSlater agree, there is not a well-defined neither a common-sense way to tell from two different ranges which one is greater.

Answer (score 2):

`nil` is a not a usable value from a comparison operation for sorting.

If you try `<=>` between two `Comparable` objects, `a <=> b` they will always return -1, 0 or 1 for "a less than b", "a equals b", and "a greater than b" respectively.

Therefore, to sort `Range` objects, you will need to override `<=>` and define yourself what order they should sort in. Note this will have to be something you have made up in order to sort them, `Range` objects do not have an inherent or meaningful sort order.

For example, I could decide that ranges are sorted in order of start of a `Range`, and falling back to end of the `Range` if they are equal:

```
class Range
  def <=>(other)
    [min, max] <=> [other.min, other.max]
  end
end

[(1..3),(1...3),(4..5),(2..3)].sort
 => [1...3, 1..3, 2..3, 4..5]
```

Comment: `nil` is a perfectly valid return value for `<=>`, and it is used exactly like it's supposed to in this case. It means "these two objects cannot be sensibly ordered".

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Yes. I may need to adjust my first sentence. I don't mean "bad, period" I mean "bad for use in sorting"